# Cannot import ArangoDriver class in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, arangodb, aql

I have been trying to run an application in batch mode to upload data to `arango db`. But to start the driver in batch mode I tried importing `ArangoDriver` class. But the class is not accessible. It is giving import error. But I'am able to import all the other packages in `com.arangodb`. I tried creating instance as per the tutorial available here https://www.arangodb.com/2014/11/arangodb-java-driver-batch-asynchronous-mode/'. But Iam not able to import anything. Has new changes have come to arango? How to resolve this?

Comment: Such features are no longer supported by the java driver. Here you can find the official documentation: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/drivers/java-reference.html

Comment: @rashtao so there is no way of doing this with spring boot?